# What is the largest file size one can store on a disk that uses inodes and disk blocks

Tags: operating-system

I have a question here that I do not know how to calculate the maximal size of a file that one can store on a disk that uses inodes and disk blocks.

Assuming a page size of 4096 bytes, a page table entry that points to a frame takes 8 bytes (4
bytes for the pointer plus some flags), and a page table entry that points to another page table
takes 4 bytes, how many levels of page tables would be required to map a 32-bit address space if
each level page table must fit into a single page?

What the maximal file size one can store on a disk that uses inodes and disk blocks that store 4096 bytes. Each inode can store 10 entries, and the first inode reserves the last two entries for cascading inode???

For the first part of the question, I got the total number of levels is 3, but I do not know how to do the second part.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like the EXT filesystem.

EXT3 uses a total of 15 pointers.

The first 12 entries are direct: they point directly to data blocks.  The third to final entry is a level 1 indirect: it points to a block filled entirely with level 1 entries.  The second to final entry is a level 2 indirect: it points to a block completely full of level 1 indirects.  The last entry is a level 3 indirect.

The maximum file size on this system is usually a restriction of the operating system, and is usually between 16GB and 2TB.

The theoretical maximum is 12I + I^2/P + I^3/P^2 + I^4/P^3, where I is the inode size in bytes (typically 4096, though different values are possible), and P is the pointer size, in bytes (4).  This yields a maximum theoretical size of 4,402,345,721,856 bytes.

[EXT3 Inode pointer structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode_pointer_structure)

Comment: I forgot to add the first part of the question:
Assuming a page size of 4096 bytes, a page table entry that points to a frame takes 8 bytes (4
bytes for the pointer plus some 
ags), and a page table entry that points to another page table
takes 4 bytes, how many levels of page tables would be required to map a 32-bit address space if each level page table must t into a single page?

In this part of the question, I got the total number of level is 3.

Comment: 3 seems correct.  2 levels would provide enough to index 2GB, which is only 31 bits.  The first page table would be level 1 indirects, that pointed to page tables.  The second page tables would be direct and would point to frames.  The first table has 2^10 entries, all of the second tables have 2^9, each frame is 2^12 bytes.  Product is 2^(10+9+12) == 2^31.